# Does standard ASP.NET dropdownlist allow selected item to be copied/CTRL-C

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

This could be an amazingly dumb question, but ....

I don't think a standard ASP.NET dropdownlist has a "copy" function when using the context menu or CTRL-C, but a colleague insists it does and he's seen it on other sites.

The website we've written doesn't allow copy, so if the dropdownlist does allow it, what is the property to enable it?

This is standard ASP.NET control, not using javascript or any special voodoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask your colleague to provide an example.

The standard `<asp:DropDownList />` control renders to the client as a standard HTML `<select />` element which does not provide copy functionality via CTRL-C or a context menu.

There is no property to enable/disable copying via an HTML `<select />` element. Whenever I want to copy something from these, I have to do it from "view source".

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so... But there's one control which may have all the functionality you want

Have a look at this:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx